# printing numbers in python in order

Tags: python

I need to print all the lists of numbers in python.

so far I wrote this:

```py
def lists(listNum, i):    
    if i == len(listNum) - 1:
       print listNum    
    else:    
        for j in range(index, len(listNum)):
            listNum[i], listNum[j] = listNum[j], listNum[i]    
            lists(listNum, i + 1)    
            listNum[i], listNum[j] = listNum[j], listNum[i]     
lists([1, 2, 3], 0)
```

how can I print every list only once?
If the list is 1,1,2 so it will print some of them twice.
how can I prevent this ?

Comment: Are they short for `permutation` and long for `i` respectively?

Comment: Theoretically, you don't need to `import itertools` to use them... You could just ctrl-f for `def permutations` in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and copy-paste the existing implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting an ascending sequence because of the swapping. Whenever you swap two elements inside the inner loop which aren't next to each other then `listNum(i+1:)` becomes un-sorted and therefore your permutations don't appear in ascending order.

To fix this you have to swap the `i` element to the second position which can do by swapping sub-sequences as follows:

```
def permutation(listNum, i):    
    if i == len(listNum) - 1:
       print listNum    
    else:    
        for j in range(i, len(listNum)):
            if j != i:
                listNum[i], listNum[j] = listNum[j], listNum[i]    
                listNum[i+1:j+1] = listNum[j:j+1] + listNum[i+1:j]    
            permutation(listNum, i + 1)    
            # now swap it back
            if j != i:
                listNum[i+1:j+1] = listNum[i+2:j+1] + listNum[i+1:i+2]
                listNum[i], listNum[j] = listNum[j], listNum[i]
```

You should probably also sort the `listNum` before you start the algorithm to handle unsorted input.

Comment: Do you know how can I print every permutation only once? If the list is 1,1,2 so it will print some of them twice.

Comment: @gali You can keep track of elements you swapped into the `i`-th position in a set and make sure you don't swap the same element twice. That will produce only unique permutations.

Comment: I try to do something like I posted up.. I got lost.

Comment: @gali I think it's better if you open another question and I and other people will try to help. I don't think you are supposed to edit your question like that here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Permutation is an organization in which order matters. Thus, if you were to sort by ascending, you'd get many lines that read `[1, 2, 3]` which isn't what you want. Keep the order as is.